# Frozen Asparagus after thawed became extremely soggy and wet, any way to salvage?

Tags: food-preservation, asparagus

So I bought a bunch of asparagus from Costco and because I didn't want to use them immediately, I froze them. This week I decided to take them out to thaw in the fridge so I let it sit overnight.

What ended up happening was the ice melted and the whole bag got soaked so now they are all wet and a little mushy? Is there a way to salvage them? I plan on just baking them but idk if they are okay to eat anymore. Or is it okay if they are wet? After reading [how to actually store asparagus](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15114/whats-the-best-way-to-store-asparagus), I probably know now I don't need to thaw them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably won't be an appetizing texture to eat whole by itself no matter what you do to it at this point, though you can try draining and cooking - your tolerance for mushiness might be higher than mine!

I'd personally blend it into a soup, so the texture isn't an issue. Things like cream of asparagus just need the flavor, which should still be okay.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I ate em and yeah they were a little soggy so I made cream of asparagus as you suggested! Unfortunately my blender sucked but it was fun!